# Error Code about "unclosed <a>?

Tags: html, expression

Why is this code (below) coming up as an error telling me that "the `<a>` tag was not closed before the `</h1>` tag"?

```
<a href="http://sap/univertical/mysite5/default.htm"><span class="style4">Training Portal</span></a></span><a></h1>
```

BTW I am new to coding and web development and have quite literally thrown into the ring of fire on this project. ANY help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: That link is not a link anyone can reach: "http: //sap/univertical/mysite5/default.htm" (space after "http:" inserted by me so that the URL is not converted by this website but displayed as text)

Comment: The page you linked to is on an intranet. Paste your code in something like http://pastebin.com, or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ah, now it is clear that you posted the code. It sounded like the code was at that URL... anyway, in addition to what's in the answers (3 right now) below, there is no <h1> tag but an </h1>, which none of them mentions.

Answer (score 4):

At the very end of the HTML string you posted, there is `<a></h1>` - an *opening* `a` tag that doesn't get closed before the `H1` tag gets closed..

It should probably not be there.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put each tag on it's own line for the sake of clarity:

```
<a href="http://sap/univertical/mysite5/default.htm">
    <span class="style4">
        Training Portal
    </span>
</a>
</span>
<a>
</h1>
```

The last three lines are all problematic.

First, there's a closing `span` tag with no matching opening tag.

Second, there's a bare `a` tag with no attributes, nor any closing tag.  This is the problem the error message is informing you about.

Third, there's a closing `h1` tag on the last line, also without a matching opening tag.

Comment: What about the unopened </h1>?

Comment: Thanks.  That looks a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
<a href="http://sap/univertical/mysite5/default.htm"><span class="style4">Training Portal</span></a></span></h1>
```

also, there is an extra  but I'm not sure if it is just there to close a span tag from before.